# Android: cut a part off a bitmap and scale it

Tags: android, bitmap, textview, android-canvas

First I want to say, that I really read much but I didn't find exactly this problem...

At the moment my code does work well. I have a bitmap, then I cut a part of my bitmap and draw this.

```
this.card = new ImageView(this); //this is my ImageView
//and my bitmap...
this.bmCards = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cardgame);

//and here I set the bitmap as Image of this ImageView
this.card.setImageBitmap(getCard(Stapel.getCard()));
```

the method, that is called is the following:

```
private Bitmap getCard(Card c) {

    //some arithmetic to calculate the size...

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(cardW, cardH, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmCards, new Rect(x, y, x + cardW + toleranzW, y + cardH + toleranzH), 
            new Rect(0, 0, cardW, cardH), new Paint());

    return result;
}
```

so far it works.. but how could I resize this Image?
I mean on the canvas I draw the right part of the Bitmap but I want to scale this part a little bit, because it's too small... maybe to actualH * 1,5 and actualW * 1,5 or something.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use this:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, originalBitmap.getWidth(),
                originalBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false);
```

and after you get the resized bitmap you can draw it on the canvas..

**EDIT**

Please try this.. I didn't tried it out.. you should play with the values as I wrote you in the comments.. and also you should read the [createBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean%29) and [postScale()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#postScale%28float,%20float%29) documentations to get to know what you are doing there :)

```
private Bitmap getCard(Card c) {

    //some arithmetic to calculate the size...

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(cardW, cardH, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(20, 20);
    result = Bitmap.createBitmap(result, 0, 0, result.getWidth(),
                    result.getHeight(), matrix, false);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmCards, new Rect(x, y, x + cardW + toleranzW, y + cardH + toleranzH), 
            new Rect(0, 0, cardW, cardH), new Paint());

    return result;
}
```

Comment: yes.. I saw something like this.. but I dont really know what I should size, because I cut and draw at the same time and I don't really know how what size I should set to "result" because my canvas is created with "result"

Comment: I understand from your question that you want to resize the Bitmap to a specific size.. is that correct? If is corect then just play a bit with the scaleWidth and scaleHeight until you get what you want.. if I didn't got this right, please be more specific on what you want.. :)

Comment: could you maybe adapt your example to my code, because I saw something like you wrote before, but I don't exactly know how to use it in my code.. in this case I stuck a little bit

Comment: hmm.. the problem is now, if I write matrix.postScale(0.5f,0.5f) it only shows 1/4 of the picture.. the top left.. and if I edit the size of result to 2*cardW, 2*cardH the picture isn't scaled anymore

Comment: I could make it smaller.. by using matrix.postScale(2,2) but if i make it bigger it doesn't fit, like I said

Comment: Then you should also make some changes to your drawBitmap() method and play with the Rect variables.. that should be the issue now

Comment: no.. the same effect.. thats now the same problem, I had, before I asked this question.. :(

Comment: I could do, what I want, I can't make it bigger the maximum is the original size

Answer (score 2):

Use a Matrix to do translations & rotations before you draw it. This is usually the easiest way.