# Android how to stretch a particular section of a Image?

Tags: android, image, android-canvas, bitmapimage

I am developing a photography app in which I want to select a particular section of a photo and stretch that portion only. How to do that?
I have tried to stretch a photo using `Canvas` but failed to do so. Is it possible from **`android.graphics.NinePatch`** class?
Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177546/android-cut-a-part-off-a-bitmap-and-scale-it

Comment: @NIPHIN I don't want to cut part of image or bitmap, want to stretch selected area of image and merge to original image.

Comment: why you don't use pinch to zoom in selected area and save that canvas as bitmap?

Comment: because i don't want to stretch or zoom whole image.

Comment: @HarshitRathi I think nine patches have nothing to do with your problem and those wouldn't help IMO. However don't trust me. Gather more info.

Answer (score 0):

A rather ugly solution would be using a [image cropping library](https://github.com/cesards/CropImageView). You can use it to temporarily crop a portion of the image and load it into another `ImageView` and then scaling it up.

Also, you can get things done without using that `CropImageView`. The idea is whenever user touches the original image view, you will be given a (x, y) at which user's finger resides. So, you can extract a bitmap image centered at (x, y) and with a given radius.

For applying a magnifier effect you could use a [round/circular ImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) for showing magnified portion of the image.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: I already used these libs, but i don't want to crop. I want to stretch part of image and merge to original image simultaneously.

Comment: @HarshitRathi What do you mean by "stretch"? zoom or dragging to smudge?

Comment: It means to enlarge some part of image and applying to original image.

Comment: @HarshitRathi OK. I just misunderstood your requirement. However I think NIPHIN's answer will address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use matrix to apply new dimension to your bitmap.
you could use `setscale`/`postScale` methods of a matrix object.

Comment: How can it possible, do you have some example?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution of my problem below :

```
Bitmap stretchImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h+progress, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );

                c = new Canvas(stretchImage); 

                //draw top bit
                c.drawBitmap(normalImage, new Rect(0,0,w,75), new Rect(0,0,w,75), null);

                //draw middle bit
                c.drawBitmap(normalImage, new Rect(0,75,w, 150), new Rect(0,75,w,150+progress), null);

                //draw right bit
                c.drawBitmap(normalImage, new Rect(0 ,150,w,225), new Rect(0 ,150+progress,w,225+progress), null); 

                myImage.setImageBitmap(stretchImage);
```